# C++ Object Default Variable

Tags: c++, string, class, oop, object

When using a string object, you can set the object equal to a string literal. How is this possible? The object consists of multiple functions and variables, so how can you just set it equal to one string literal?

Thanks!

Edit:

Sorry for the confusing question.

It makes sense to me that you can set a variable or array equal to a value. For example:

```
char word[3] = {'c', 'a', 'r'};
```

But a string is not simply a variable, so what in its class allows you to write a statement setting the object to a value?

```
string word = "car";
```

I would love to do this in my objects, but thus far I have been using something like this, where objectTemp is the class & tempF is a member holding the temperature value in Fahrenheit:

```
objectTemp cat;
cat.tempF = 102;
```

Comment: *How is this possible?* Are you asking how `std::string str = "Hello"` is possible?

Comment: What C++ textbook are you learning from?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's not very clear exactly what you're asking. Could you maybe post some specific code that you can't understand, with specific questions?

Comment: Yes, Dean Seo, that's exactly what I am asking.

Comment: JMAA, I edited the question to try to clarify it, and added some code.

Comment: It's worth noting that functions are stored _per-class_ in your program, not per-object. Every `string` has the exact same members functions as any other `string`, and the compiler is well aware of this, and so doesn't store that information with each `string` object, referring to the correct functions instead simply by type inference (ignoring `virtual` functions for now).

Comment: @alterigel Oh got it! That makes more sense. Thanks for clearing that up for me :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is possible because C++ knows of "magic" functions that are called upon object instantiation called constructors.

The other "magic" function you should look up is the assignment operator.

> But a string is not simply a variable, so what in its class allows you to write a statement setting the object to a value?
>
> ```
> string word = "car";
> ```

As said before, one of the constructors of [`std::string`](https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) makes this magic happen:

```
std::string::string(char const*);
```

It takes a pointer to constant `char`s which are interpreted as a "C-string" (a zero-terminated string).

> I would love to do this in my objects, but thus far I have been using something like this, where objectTemp is the class & tempF is a member holding the temperature value in Fahrenheit:
>
> ```
> objectTemp cat;
> cat.tempF = 102;
> ```

Write a constructor for your class (=don't be afraid of the magic) which takes a numeric value as its parameter. Eg.

```
class objectTemp {
    int tempF;
public:
    objectTemp(int tempF)  // constructors are named the same as the struct/class
    : tempF{ tempF }  // initializer-list
    {}  // an empty body
}
```

usage:

```
objectTemp cat = 102;
```

or:

```
objectTemp cat(102);
```

or:

```
objectTemp cat{ 102 };
```

Comment: There's nothing like _magic_ in c++. Stop spreading such myths please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Everyone knows that there is magic in C++ which makes programs written in C++ so slow compared to programs written in C!

Comment: _"... which makes programs written in C++ so slow compared to programs written in C!"_ That's just another myth. As mentioned stop telling such please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That are facts. You'd probably also call the cost of exception handling a myth.

Comment: How can this be? For he **IS** the Kwisatz Haderach!

Comment: Thanks for the example! I couldn't get the exact example code working, but it helped me get this working:

`class objectTemp`
`{`
  `int tempF;`
`public:`
 `objectTemp(int temp)`
 ` {`
    `tempF = temp;`
  `}`
`};`

Comment: @sharkByte Wait. What in my example using the initializer list was "not working"?

Comment: @Swordfish Woops! Nevermind! Sorry I messed up. It works great :). It was an issue with my text editor :P.

Comment: @sharkByte I'm relieved ;)

Answer (score 4):

C++ supports operator overload which allows to call the function:

```
string& operator= (const char* s);
```

of class `std::string`.
This simply takes a `const char*` (literal) and create internally the new `std::string` object.

Comment: So ... `std::string foo = "bar";` calls a function named `operator=()`?

Comment: @Swordfish Nope, it calls the _magic_ constructor overload.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ha! You said it! ;)

Comment: Hm. "This simply takes a const char* (literal)" can i only assign string literals then?

Comment: No, it is just an implementation of many. Find more here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/

Comment: Hm. Which one is called for `char foo[] = "bar"; std::string qux = foo;`?

Comment: char[] is nothing else but char* so your foo variable in that case is const char* . You have your answer.

Comment: @NikosXenakis "char[] is nothing else but char*" Certainly not.

Comment: The variable name of a table in c++ is just a pointer nothing else. For example, foo[1] == *(foo + 1*sizeof(char)) for valid memory access. Read about the introduction to c++ tables, or just test it in your code, it will be clear to you then. Have fun :)

Comment: @NikosXenakis That `foo[n]` is the same as `*(foo + n)` doesn't change the fact that the type of `foo` is `char[4]` and not `char *` or `char const *`.

Comment: @Swordfish char[4] just reserves memory in the stack and not in the heap as "new" would do with char*. If you keep having doubts please submit a new question. Maybe someone else is also confused and want things to be cleared. Thanks

Comment: @NikosXenakis  don't think that this is worth a question on its own if you can just make this clear to me: in `char foo[] = "bar";` the `foo` is a `char*` and `"qux"` is of type `char const*`?

Comment: if by "qux" you mean a literal string then yes.

Comment: @NikosXenakis And `foo`?

Comment: as you said foo is a pointer to a char

Comment: @NikosXenakis You are wrong on both. http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string#8 http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.string#1

Comment: @NikosXenakis `"qux"` is of type `char const[4]` and `foo` in `char foo[] = "bar";` is of type `char[4]`.

Comment: There is neither type char const[4] nor char[4] in c++ language. const char* and char* are the types you are looking for. Please start from the basics before you get more confused. Happy coding!

Comment: @NikosXenakis You didn't even bother to look at the links I gave you.

Comment: @NikosXenakis "There is neither type char const[4] nor char[4] in c++ language." Mhm. so ... `char const a[4];` ... of what type is `a`? ... `char b[4];` ... of what type is `b`?

Comment: @NikosXenakis Thanks for the answer! It helped me out :)

Comment: @NikosXenakis Here you are: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52827290/3975177