# Type of strings

Tags: c++, string-literals

I got quite confused about what is what. Would you please tell me what each variables type is?

```cpp
char foo[] = "bar";
char *bar = nullptr;
char const *qux = nullptr;
```

Aditionally, what is the type of `"bar"`?

Comment: the type is the thing you say they are... "bar" is const char[] which degrades into const char *, and is legal as an initializer for char[4]

Comment: See [string_literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

Comment: @songyuanyao If you could write that as an answer and also explain which type `"bar`" is of, i could accept that as answer.

Comment: @songyuanyao Please write an answer. The comment you made is exactly the answer I am looking for. (let the confusion be my problem ;) )

Comment: This could all be answered by any basic C tutorial.

Comment: @KenWhite If you can point me to one (regardless if C or C++) that points out the differences between string literals, `char`-arrays and pointers to `char` correctly ... kudos to you.

Comment: @GradyPlayer: No, `"bar"` does not decay to `const char*` in that context (when it's used to initialize an array). In C, the contexts in which array-to-pointer decay does *not* occur are (a) the operand of `sizeof`, (b) the operand of unary `&`, and (c) a string literal used to initialize an array object. (There may be other cases in C++.)

Comment: @KeithThompson "(There may be other cases in C++.)" Can't think of any.

Comment: @downvoters WhyTF deserves this question 4 downvotes!?!?!?!? Whats f...erdammtnochmal wrong with it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `foo` is `char[4]`, i.e. a [character array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal#Notes) containing 4 `char`s (including the trailing null character `'\0'`.)

> String literals can be used to initialize character arrays. If an array is initialized like `char str[] = "foo";`, `str` will contain a copy of the string `"foo"`.

The type of `bar` is `char *`, `qux` is `char const *`, just as you declared.

`"bar"` is [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal#Notes) with type `const char[4]`, i.e. an array containing 4 `const` `char`s (also including the trailing null character `'\0'`.)

> The null character (`'\0'`, `L'\0'`, `char16_t()`, etc) is always appended
>   to the string literal: thus, a string literal `"Hello"` is a `const char[6]` 
>   holding the characters `'H'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'`, and `'\0'`.

Here's a helper class which could give the exact type at compile-time (the idea is borrowed from *Effective.Modern.C++* written by *Scott Meyers*).

```
template <typename>
struct TD;
```

then use it like

```
TD<decltype(foo)> td1;
TD<decltype("bar")> td2;
TD<decltype(bar)> td3;
TD<decltype(qux)> td4;
```

e.g. from [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gE2ghrwjXRXehW9C) you'll get error message containing type information like:

> ```
> prog.cc:12:23: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'TD<char [4]>'
>     TD<decltype(foo)> td1;
>                       ^
> prog.cc:13:25: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'TD<char const (&)[4]>'
>     TD<decltype("bar")> td2;
>                         ^
> prog.cc:14:23: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'TD<char *>'
>     TD<decltype(bar)> td3;
>                       ^
> prog.cc:15:23: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'TD<const char *>'
>     TD<decltype(qux)> td4;
>                       ^
> ```

---

BTW: Because [string literals are treated as lvalues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10004511/3309790), and [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) yields type of `T&` for lvalues, so the above message from clang gives the type of `"bar"` as an lvalue-reference to array, i.e. `char const (&)[4]`.

Comment: Hey, nice trick! Much clearer than the gibberish one gets from `typeid(T).name()`.

Comment: Only the type of `"bar"` is missing in your answer. Maybe you can add that.

Comment: @Swordfish Sorry I missed that. Added now.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding `TD<decltype("bar")> td2;` to the code example.

Comment: @Swordfish Fine. BTW the idea of helper class is borrowed from the book *Effective.Modern.C++* written by *Scott Meyers*.

Comment: Oh, i knew of "Effective C++" and "More Effective C++" but didn't know he has written another.

Comment: @Swordfish It's written for C++11 and C++14 features.

Comment: Too bad we're at C++17 and C++20 now. Poor Scotty ... needs to catch up ... fast ;) Maybe Bjarne, Herb or Andrei will beam him up?

Answer (score -1):

The variable `foo` is a character array. Sort of.

Somewhere in the memory of your computer the compiler has organised things so that it contains the bytes `[ 0x62, 0x61, 0x72, 0x00 ] "bar\0"`.  The compiler added the trailing `\0` (0x00) for you, to mark the end of the string.  Let's say the compiler put these bytes at memory address 0x00001000 - the 4096th byte.

So even though we think of `foo` as a character array, the variable `foo` is actually the address of the first element of those four bytes, so `foo = 0x00001000`.

The variable `bar` is a *pointer*, which is just a number.  The number it holds is the address in memory of whatever it is "pointing at".  Initially you set `bar` to be `nullptr`, so (probably) `bar = 0x00000000`.

It's quite OK to say:

```
bar = foo;
```

Which would mean that `bar` now *points at* `foo`.  Since we said the bytes for `foo` were stored at some location in memory (an "address"), that number is just copied into `bar`.  So now `bar = 0x00001000` too.

The variable `qux` is a pointer to a constant variable.  This is a special compiler note so it can generate an error if you try to modify what it's pointing at.

It's OK to code:

```
qux = foo;
qux = bar;
```

Since all these things are pointers to characters.

Comment: What do you mean by "The variable foo is a character array. Sort of." Sort of?

Comment: "The compiler added the trailing \0 (0x00) for you, to mark the end of the string." The compiler adds a `'\0'` to foo? What about the `"bar"`?

Comment: @Swordfish - I write "sort of" because I went on to describe what it is, and it's not a `character array`, it the address of the first element of that character array in the machine's memory.  So in effect, it's a pointer.   The `bar` variable is purely a pointer, no memory bytes are allocated for it by the compiler.

Comment: Under that circumstances, go read songyuanyao's answer. He is right, you are wrong.

Comment: First you talk about a variable: "The `bar` variable is purely a pointer, no memory bytes are allocated for it by the compiler." and now about a literal: "`TD<decltype("bar")> td2;`" That doesn't make much sense, since a literal can't be declared.

Comment: @Swordfish - Songyuanyao's is referring to the `bar` variable in his answer, not your question.  The variable `bar` in your question does not generate a string in memory, it points to nullptr / NULL / 0.

Comment: Sorry, got confused with `foo` and `bar`. "I write 'sort of' because I went on to describe what it is, and it's not a character array, it the address of the first element of that character array in the machine's memory." is still plain wrong.